# Can I make a custom pagination in backpack 4.1?

Tags: laravel-backpack

**Introduction**: I'm trying to make a custom pagination in a backpack panel where there is a table ([table_300_products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5mcU.png)) with more than 300 products. I don't want users to go one by one page If they want to reach the page 290 for example. I want like a tiny search bar where you can enter the number and will direct you to the 290 page with the products (when you press enter). Here goes an edited graphic example: [edited_graphic_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFrcp.png).

**Doubts I have**: Is it possible in the backpack 4.1 version? How should I do it? Which vendor file do I need to modify?

I checked out the [4.1 documentation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-api), and I didn't see nothing about customizing the pagination. Also, I tried to search in the vendor file If there is some file that I could modify but I didn't find out which file.

Answer (score 0):

Hi [@fercor3000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21743033/fercor3000) It's related to `datatables` inside `list` operations.

For this, you will find datatables setup here
`vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/crud/list.blade.php`
`vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/crud/inc/datatables_logic.blade.php`

create a copy of them, customize & use it for you particular CRUD using:

`$this->crud->setListView('path.to.your.view');`

Comment: I've already made the "copies" and I overwrite the originals ones, but what part of the list.blade.php or datatables_logic.blade.php is related to the paginator? Because I want to modify that specific parts so I can customize the paginator of backpack.